# JavaScript: for Loop inside function stops based on user input

Tags: javascript, function, loops, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a javascript code where I can have the user input a number to count the loop that many times.

The loop is supposed to run the Fibonacci numbers in order as many times as specified and stop. I was asked to have the loop inside a function.

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvYD2.png)

```js
< !DOCTYPE HTML >
  <
  html >
  <
  title > Fibonacci < /title> <
  head >
  <
  script >
  function chkInput() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById = ("userInput").value;
    var outputString = "" + (i);
    var a, b, r;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    r = b;
    for (var i = 1; i <= num1; i++) {
      outputString += "</br>" + (r * num1);
      r = a + b;
      a = b;
      b = r;
    }
    document.write(outputString);
  }

  <
  /script> <
  /head> <
  body >
  <
  input type = "text"
id = "userInput" >
  <
  input type = "button"
id = "btn"
value = "Enter"
onclick = "chkInput()" >
  <
  /body> <
  /html>
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far?

Comment: please show us where you are so far with this as this sounds like homework. You will gain nothing from someone posting an answer. But if we can help you work through it you will learn more.

Comment: And what is the question? What is the problem with your code?

Comment: sorry it's my first time on here had a problem putting the code in so I had to put it in as a link

Answer (score 0):

Works well... where n is the number elements

```
function chkInput(){
 var num1 = document.getElementByID =("userInput").value;
  document.write(fibonacci_series(num1 ));
}
```

& then [the Fibonacci series as per this doc](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-recursion-function-exercise-6.php)

```
var fibonacci_series = function (n) 
{
  if (n===1) 
  {
    return [0, 1];
  } 
  else 
  {
    var s = fibonacci_series(n - 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    return s;
  }
};
```

The array fibonacci_series contains the series... & return keyword here is like the loop stopper

Comment: This appears to be an exact copy of the code here: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-recursion-function-exercise-6.php. Please consider putting a link in your answer to where you found the code.